# Restore MKMapView visible state/region properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, viewstate, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a little iPad app which shows a MKMapView instance (`map`). In order to save the state I try saving the `map.region` to the NSUserDefaults. This works very well storing only the single values as doubles. On launching, the app combines the numbers and produces a valid `MKCoordinateRegion`. This happens in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Now there are several problems.

**1)** Imagine: You leave the app in landscape orientation. The app saves the corresponding `MKCoordinateRegion`. The app is terminated. Now, holding the iPad landscape, launching the app, the map doesn't show the same state as before leaving the app. And no, this is not a problem of `regionThatFits:`. I tracked it down and this is what happens: Also when it isn't visible to the user, the app starts in portrait mode. The app restores his state. After that the map is rotated into landscape mode.

With other words the app saves the landscape state but restores it to portrait. If you repeat these steps the map zooms out with every launch. Not the best UX.

**2)** Even if problem one would be solved by restoring in the right orientation there is still the problem that the launching orientation could differ from the leaving orientation. I think one of the better ways to solve this is to store always the values for the portrait orientation also when the user leaves in landscape. By doing this the state would be restored properly because the app is launched initially in portrait by the system.

One possible way would be to change the latitude/longitude values if the app is left in landscape. But this would be too inaccurate because `CLLocationDegrees` differ if they are latitude or longitude.

An other way (and I think this would be the best way) would be to "simulate" a rotation of the mapview or to calculate the visible region for the portrait mode when the app is left. But I really don't know how to do this. Here is the point where I need your help and your ideas.

I appreciate every ray of hope. :) — And please tell me if I think into a wrong direction.

Comment: Tried it with `map.visibleRect` and `MKMapRect`, calculating the rotation by switching width and height and moving the origin. I thought it be more accurate than `CLLocationDegrees` but it has also some side effects. I think the only way is to force the map to calculate the values instead of calculating myself.

Comment: Is the map view on the root view controller or some other?  Where exactly is `setRegion` called?  In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, other?

Comment: [AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]
-> inits UINavigationController
    -> rootViewController is a custom ViewController which holds the MapView
    -> restore of the `map.region` happens in `loadView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. If I understand your question correctly, you're saving the MKMapView's `region` (that is, its `center` and `span`), and would like to use these values to restore the map's center and *zoom level*, independently of whether the user rotates the device between sessions.

Have you tried calculating the width-to-height ratio of your map rectangle, and then multiplying out the changes to the span? That is, if your map has bounds of size 800 x 600 in landscape mode, then you'd multiply the longitudeDelta by 600/800 (0.75) and the latitudeDelta by 800/600 (1.33) to get the appropriate span for a 600 x 800 rectangle in portrait mode.

Comment: I really like your idea, but if you leave and relaunch the app it zooms out every time. I think, this is again a problem of `regionThatFits:` (which is called automatically by setting the `map.region`) because applying the ratio to the coordinates calculates a "broken" zoom-level for the region.

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea! If you substract an half degree of the calculated latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta the map fits to the right zoom-level. :)